# React-Radar package is not exporting Radar from react-radar?

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, components, radar-chart

*I have a simple react app in which i just want to show a radar and get point on radar in JSON.

[image]

For this purpose i heard about react-radar package from my friend.
i read the package documentation from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-radar/v/0.2.0-alpha.3
but when i try to implement this.
I get the following errors

> Attempted import error: 'react-radar' does not contain a default
> export (imported as 'Radar').

i try to solve this error by placing {} around component then i get the following error

> Attempted import error: 'Radar' is not exported from 'react-radar'.

code is in documentation.Kindly guide me
picture is attached.

Comment: but the docs says it is for data fetching and state management

Comment: @Punit Makwana kindly suggest me something useful for creating this type of radar in react js